# how to find Vout/Vin in this circuit? BJT frequency response

Tags: capacitor, bjt, gain, frequency-response, small-signal

I have been struggling for 1 hour trying to relate Vout to Vin. However, I truly cannot. I tried KVL, node analysis etc everything that I could. Can you help me pls? The topic is frequency response of BJT amplifiers. I found and draw small signal model. The circuit has 1 capacitor. I drown in equations and unknown variables. Can you guide me in the right direction so that I can easily solve such questions? I do not want to make use of Rin as it is comlicated. I all the time get devastated by questions involving emitter resistor.

[image: the circuit]

Comment: Try Vout/Vin = Rc/Re * Ic * k then compute Ib to get Ic with attenuation k of impedance ratio to the emitter voltage

Comment: Then compare an example of this simulation to your result https://tinyurl.com/y8zqnsef